# Why I'm getting this error in Node.js mysql2 config: "...SSL alert number 70"?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl, mysql2

I'm trying to connect my backend server to an instance of Cloud SQL. Everything works fine until I try to connect to the instance of mysql via ssl using the config options os mysql2.

This is my config options:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const poolExample = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'host ip',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'database_name',
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0,
  // debug: true,
  ssl: {
     ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/directory/server-ca.pem'),
     key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/directory/client-key.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/directory/client-cert.pem'),
   },
 });
```

I need to connect to this instance via ssl because my backend runs on App Engine so I can't use unsecure protocol or authorizing any IP address. This method works fine with sequelize but with mysql2 I receive this error:

```
"Error: 4482158016:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 70\n"
```

What is wrong with this kind of approach?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a deprecated cypher or TLS (formerly called SSL) protocol version.

The server you're trying to communicate does not allow connections using the old and broken versions of TLS.

Check in the comand line if this is accepted, try both versions, 1.1 and 1.3:

```
openssl s_client -port 3306 -host host.ip.address -tls1_3
openssl s_client -port 3306 -host host.ip.address -tls1_1
```

There are additional versions allowed and blocked currently.

You need to use the modern parameters, which might also change in the future. See this list:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem
ssl-cipher=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
# replication:
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* to ‘repl’@’%’ REQUIRE SSL;
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER MASTER_SSL=1,
MASTER_SSL_CA=’/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem’,
MASTER_SSL_CERT=’/etc/mysql-ssl/client-cert.pem’,
MASTER_SSL_KEY=’/etc/mysql-ssl/client-key.pem';
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
START SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
```